# Similarity class of $3 \times 3$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{F}_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, jordan-normal-form

I've been trying to solve the following problem.

Find a representative for each similarity class of $3 \times 3$ matrices $A$ with entries in $\mathbb{F}_3 = \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ such that $A^4 = A$.

My idea: if $A$ is an invertible matrix, then $A^3 = I$ which implies that the minimum polynomial of $A$ divides $x^3 - 1 = (x - 1)(x + 2)(x + 2)$. At this point,  I can analyze all the possible cases and determine from these cases the similarity classes. However, if $A$ is not invertible then I will have too many cases to analyze; so I am not sure if I am approaching this from the wrong perspective.

Comment: Do you know the rational canonical form?

Comment: yes, when I say analyze all possible cases I am referring to compute the different rational canonical forms once I determine all invariant factors.

Comment: In $\Bbb F_3$ we have $x + 2 = x - 1$, so $x^3 - 1 = (x - 1)^3$.

Comment: Ah, you are totally right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to consider the invertible case separately. The minimal polynomial of $A$ must divide $x^4-x=x(x^3-1)=x(x-1)^3$ over $\mathbb F_3$. This will give the possible forms for the characteristic polynomial, which has degree $3$ and must have exactly the same irreducible factors as the minimal polynomial. There are many cases, but it's not that complicated.

Comment: +1, but I only get $7$ cases, is that really "many"?